# Does asp.net mvc Url.Content encode the string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does asp.net mvc Url.Content encode the input or should I also use Url.Encode on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28VS.90%29.aspx) it only expands the *~* character.  If that character does not exist then the path is returned as it was passed in.

You can also test it.  Using ASP.Net 4.0 it did not for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Content method just converts a virtual path to an absolute application path. What is there to Encode?